# EF convert nullable var in varchar

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The main question is, how to filter a repository with LinqToEntities when we have a column name as string and a value as string and that we dont know the type of the column in DB?

After many investigations, i've found that it's not possible to translate

```
db.entities.Where(x=>x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x).ToString().Contains("a string"))
```

into

```
select *
from table
where cast(columnName as varchar) like '%a string%'
```

because .ToString() is not compatible with LinqToEntities where it's fully compatible with LinqToObject.

A possible bypass can be build a stored procedure to do the job but if there can be a solution with EF it would be best.

Comment: Do you know the column name? Because currently, you are using Reflection which isn't compatible with EF...

Comment: It's exactly my problem, i want to make a generic method to filter my repository that's why the column name is contained in a string passed as parameter to the method and so i can't use direct filters

Answer (score 0):

I think [Linq Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) should do the trick:

```
// Select string properties
var columns = typeof(Entity).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)).Select(c => c.Name + " == @0");
// Aggregate
var queryString = string.Join(" || ", columns);
// Query with Linq Dynamic
var query = db.Entities.Where(queryString, "MyString");
```

Comment: Your solution offers only "equal" when i need a "contains" and not only on string type but on every types